# Calculating average NETWORK days Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been reading various [threads](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/NETWORKDAYS-type-function-in-PowerBI/td-p/154902) and guides to performing a 'NETWORKDAYS' style calculation in Power BI but struggling to make it work.

I have a table like this:

```
Team |  Meeting    |  Report
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |  9/1/2018
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |  7/1/2018
bbb  | 1/1/2018    |  1/2/2018
bbb  | 1/1/2018    | 
ccc  | 1/1/2018    |  3/3/2018
aaa  | 1/1/2018    |
```

And I want to return the average days without weekends and holidays, something like this:

```
Team | average
aaa  | 5 (10/2)
bbb  | 23 (45/1)
ccc  | 45 (45/1)
```

I have this function, which seems to work albeit clunkily, but I don't know how to remove the non-weekdays from the Date table:

```
AVERAGEX(FILTER(Planning,NOT(ISBLANK(Planning Actual_FinalReport]))),
    (COUNTROWS(DATESBETWEEN(DateTable[Date],
    Planning[Actual_ClosingMeeting],Planning [Actual_FinalReport]))
))
```

Where DateTable is:

```
Date    | Weekday
5/1/2018| 1
6/1/2018| 0
7/1/2018| 0
```

and so on...

Essentially, I want to iterate over Planning (filtering out blanks in [Report]) and count the dates between Meeting and Report from the Dates table, filtered by Weekday = 1. It's the syntax to link the tables I think I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your formula a bit, how about something like this?

```
Average = AVERAGEX(
              FILTER(Planning,
                  NOT(ISBLANK(Planning[Actual_FinalReport]))),
              COUNTROWS(
                  FILTER(DateTable,
                      DateTable[Date] IN DATESBETWEEN(
                                             DateTable[Date],
                                             Planning[Actual_ClosingMeeting],
                                             Planning[Actual_FinalReport]) &&
                      DateTable[Weekday] = 1)))
```

I'm adding the `Weekday` filter at the end.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work but I'll compare to some known values. So the second FILTER function returns a table of just the dates from the date column between the dates on the current row of planning, where weekday is 1? I'm not sure how the IN function works..

Comment: Just reading around IN, could I pass it multiple arguments, i.e. include the DateTable[Weekday] = 1 to it as well and remove the AND (&&)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I don't think so.